# How to use a USB device instead of a hard drive

Tags: debian, usb, hard-disk

Recently I setup a webcam that uses ftp, which uploads the current frame every 0.33 seconds. This creates thousands of images on my hard drives. I have a daily cron job deleting anything past 10 days old, so the space doesn't get out of hand.

I was wondering if it's safer to store all the images on a USB drive attached to my server, so that the hard drives don't have such a load on them. If I have my ftp user's home directory pointed to a mount on the usb, will the hard drives be affected?

I'm asking because my hard drives are really old, and I don't want to wear them out faster then needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ftp user's home directory pointed to a mountpoint on the usb device, and the FTP client is set to write in the default directory, the hard drives will be not be utilized for the file storage.  You may find that reads and writes are faster, but it's been my experience USB flash drives have life more limited than your hard drive.

Personally, I'd look into SSD storage or taking photos less frequently (three a second seems much) if these are sincere concerns.

Comment: Thanks. It's a video camera which only takes stills, the best frame rate I can get is 3 frames / seconds. Ideally I would want a video or like 15-30 frames. And I'm trying to do this without spending more money.